# Finding the bottleneck

Tags: apache-2.2, database, central-processing-unit, maximum

I've just begun running some tests on our application system using JMeter.  We are currently running a three-server setup.  Requests go to a load balancer, which sends it to one of two apache servers (Ubuntu).  Each of those servers has a link to a single database server running MySQL.

Here is my question:  As I run tests with 100 requests or so at a time, my two application code servers peak at about 35% CPU usage and my database sits calmly at 0.3%.  What could be causing such a high usage on the application servers?

I'm BRAND new to server admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short... your application is doing too much heavy lifting.  There are a HUGE number of reasons why this could be... and even more ways to try & debug it.  Unfortunately, there is not 1 universal tool for finding the saggy bits.  Most of the tools for doing this are platform specific... (not just OS specific, but language & framework specific)  Some are better than others.

A quick & dirty way of trying to find the saggy bits in the application... are to put in a couple of *time* checks & measure how much processing time is dedicated to various components in your code.  Once you know what bits eat up the most amounts of time... refactor, cleanup, optimize, etc... until it's running as smooth as you can make it... and start the process over.

Answer (score 0):

Following link has same tips may be it useful for

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2009/12/identifying-linux-bottlenecks.html

http://studyhat.blogspot.com/2010/08/user-activity-view-processes-display.html